# Is it impossible to monitor tensorflow weight tensor in IDE(Pycharm)?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to learn various ways to monitor tensorflow weight tensor.

I know we can watch these variable tensors through `Session.run()`, `tf.Print()`, `tf.py_func()`and tools like tensorboard, tdb, tfdbg
(https://wookayin.github.io/tensorflow-talk-debugging/#1)

But is it impossible to use IDE(like Pycharm) for this?

I tried by myself, and couldn't find some places to set a breakpoint.

Please tell me if you succeed tensor debugging using IDE. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I debug TF daily in Pycharm. I set breakpoints as usual in the left column of the editor next to the line numbers. You can also hover over the tensors (see the yellow tooltip) to see their shape and summarized contents.

[image]

Comment: how to configure PyCharm like yours to debug tensorflow?? I   want to use PyCharm to add break point during tensorflow operator process?

Comment: (1) Set up a breakpoint by clicking in the margin between line numbers and code. It'll set a red dot as above (2) At the top of the editor, click on the green insect button "Debug" next to the "Run" (triangular button), this should stop on your breakpoints. Note, that if you "Run" instead of "Debug" your breakpoints won't work. Additionally, make sure your breakpoints are in code that is reachable. i.e. that is being executed, otherwise those breakpoints won't work either. Cheers

Comment: Oh, I am sorry I didn't write clearly. In my knowledge, tensorflow's operator is not exist before session.run, it is just descriptor of data graph. So , the magic session.run wrap and hide the actual operator run process. So , I think if you use PyCharm to debug breakpoint of tensorflow  graph's operator process, It may not break point to work as you expected.

Comment: For example, If I want to break point of convolutional layers, I want to check the middle conv layer output matrix value during CNN process. PyCharm breakpoint may not debug this? I want to find a solution of debug tensorflow in PyCharm

Comment: In my example, I'm not debugging the TF sess.run(). Note the stack on the left. I'm simply debugging the graph setup, making sure my tensors are the right shape etc. I think if you want to debug your actual data flowing through a TF graph, you're better off with a framework like PyTorch that does dynamic graph creation, this is much better for hacking/debugging. I for example, have stopped using TF for "investigative" work or trying to re-implement a new paper because of the debugging limitations of the static graph. Good luck!